# Show many images on asp.net page as thumbnails

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, image, thumbnails, has-many

I have saved images uploaded by user in one of my folders.In the sql server DB I just save the file-name of the image. For one item I have nearly 5-6 images. So I have an itemID as one of the column and imagename as one column and i have 1 2 3 4 5 in the table. 
I need to display all these images in thumbnail format on a page. Like on craigslist. How do i proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript/jQuery image box to display a large image with small thumbnails.

Here are the two I know -

1. [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) (I'm currently using)
2. [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

**Or You can use the following code -**

Demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYfy5/)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container img {
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".container img").mouseover(function () {
            $("#<%= LargeImage.ClientID %>").attr("src", $(this).prop('src'));
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $("#<%= LargeImage.ClientID %>").attr("src",
            "http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image1");
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Image ID="LargeImage" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image1"
    runat="server" />
<div class="container">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image2"
        runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image3"
        runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image3" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image4"
        runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="Image4" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x400&text=Image5"
        runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Well,the thing is I can get n number of images from my DB.I need to show all of them in thumbnail format.If he clicks on one,expand it.Just like craigslist. When I saw your above 2 suggestions it seems like I need to mention beforehand all the links for images. But mine will vary.Is there any example of yours I can look at?

Comment: I am little bit new to this.I see in your code you have before hand mentioned the imageurls and 5 image elements.But mine cannot be like that. My problem is that I may/may not have images. If I place a telerik radgrid on the page and image element(itemtemplate) in the grid,would that work?Can you show me how to proceed in this format?Thanks

Comment: The idea is same even if RadGrid is used. It basically attachs mouseout event/hover to every images inside `container` div. In your case, you can set as `$(".RadGrid img")`. ***FYI***, you need to understand a little bit of jQuery or javascript in order to work at client side.

Comment: $('#imagesPreview').append('<img src="C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\TempFolder\\16.jpg" />'); I am trying to add an image to a div tag(imagesPreview) on client side. But i am getting empty image, as in its hollow.When i check the image properties it shows 16.jpg for General and all other values are Not Available. What is wrong here?

Comment: Well, web browser cannot access your local file system `src="C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\TempFolder\\16.jpg"`. It must be something like `/Images/16.jpg`.